# How to pass information from a parent Activity into a RUNNING Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, listener

I understand that `Fragments` can receive information from the parent `Activity` through methods like `onAttach()` and `implementations` of `Listeners`, but those approaches involve passing information exclusively at the conception of each `Fragment`. I'm wondering how to change information in a `Fragment` from an `Activity` while the `Fragment` is running; for instance, **in my case**, I have a `Navigation Drawer` with check items as my parent navigation `Activity`. The checks correspond to which items of an `ArrayList` should be displayed in the `Fragment.`

How can I make my `Fragment's` `ArrayList` immediately responsive to changes in the parent `Activity` without recreating the `Fragment`?

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, final int childPosition, long id) {
    checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.show_child_subject_checkBox);
    checkBox.toggle();
    tempSI = SubjectInfo.findById(SubjectInfo.class,
             childItem.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getId());
    onSubjectCheck(tempSI);
    tempSI.subjectChecked = !tempSI.subjectChecked;
    tempSI.save();
    childItem.get(groupPosition).set(childPosition, tempSI);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toggled " +groupPosition + "|" + childPosition,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // the oncheckedchangedListener now resides and operates out of adapter
    // in a much more efficient, clean manner
    return true;
}
```

`onSubjectCheck` is the implementation of the Listener in the Activity. Perhaps this is **not** the best way to do this, but I figured I'd show how I toyed around with the idea, at least.

```
@Override
public void onSubjectCheck(SubjectInfo si) {
    for (int go = 0; go < subjectList.size(); go++) {
        if (subjectList.get(go).equals(si)) {
            si = new SubjectInfo(si.subjectName, si.itemHeaderTitle, si.subjectGrade,
                    si.subjectArchived, !si.subjectChecked);
            amFragment.subjectList.set(go, si);
        }
    }
    amFragment.sorterAndFilter(false);
}
```

Comment: use interfaces to pass data from an activity to a running fragment, with the help of following link  https://laaptu.wordpress.com/tag/android-passing-data-from-activity-to-fragment/

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways you can pass information from a parent Activity to a fragment.

1. Using setArguments on Fragment.

   Fragment mFragment = new MyFragment();
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.put**(KEY,value);
   mFragment.setArguments(args);
2. Using fragment instance directly.

   Inside Activity,
   mFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id) or findFragmentByTag(tag);

   mFragment.methodCall();

Comment: The args() approach only applies to passing information at the conception of the fragment, not during the life of the fragment. When finding the fragment by tag, does it find the living fragment? When I tried to update the subject list I got a null pointer exception